# Looking for a story about hatching turtles

Tags: story-identification

There is a story I'm looking for that I read back when I was 8 (20 years ago) that got me into reading and sci-fi.

It's about a man stuck in a dark cell and he is panicking and struggling to get out and finally does. He is on a beach and many cells are there, and ends up fleeing flying monsters ripping them off the ground and climbing mountains and people getting ripped off the mountain, etc., ending with them trying to get to the water. It ends up that they are all turtles hatching, the monsters were birds, and the "people" with him are other turtles. It was a dramatic story told in sci-fi style about them trying to make it to the ocean. Any help would be nice. I believe the story starts with him in his "cell".

Comment: I'm not really sure this is scifi

Comment: It was writen in such a way as it lent it self to a character on an alien planet. The context was told in a surreal sci fi way